# Angular datepicker not updating after changing min or max date

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular11

I have a datepicker inside a mat-card like this:

```
<mat-card class="datepickerContainer">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Month and Year</mat-label>
        <input matInput [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="datePicker" [formControl]="date">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #datePicker
                        startView="multi-year"
                        (yearSelected)="yearSelectedHandler($event)"
                        (monthSelected)="monthSelectedHandler($event, datePicker)"
                        panelClass="example-month-picker">
        </mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</mat-card>
```

Inside `ngAfterViewInit()`, the min selectable year is set like this based on the year specified in a configuration object:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.configService.getConfiguration().subscribe((configs) => {
      this.minDate.setFullYear(configs.startYear);
    });
  }
```

I already debugged this and `this.minDate.setFullYear()` is being called with the correct year as parameter. However, when I now open the date picker in the frontend, it seems to be completely disabled:

[image: datepicker disabled]

I can click on the selected year (2022) but then I cannot select a month:

[image: select month disabled]

I do not disable the date picker anywhere, so why is it disabled and why is the min year not set to 2021? I also noticed that when I initially set the min date to something else (like 2021) already, it is working fine, so the problem must be related to Angular not knowing that I changed the min date in `ngAfterViewInit()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call

`ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()`

after

`this.minDate.setFullYear(configs.startYear);`

Or else Angular will not know anything changed, since Angular detects changes if the reference of an @Input changes and not if the bound object is mutated.

Comment: Is that the default change detection? I am asking because I never even heard about this before so I never changed this in a project. However, I noticed that if I already set 2021 as the default value for `this.minDate`, it works just fine. So it must indeed be related to Angular not knowing that I changed `this.minDate`. Also, when I call `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()`, Angular starts complaining that `markForCheck()` does not exist. Is this maybe for a different Angular version, or is there another way to tell angular that I changed `this.minDate`?

Comment: I was able to get `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` to work now but it still doesn't change the behaviour in any way.

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem on for example stackblitz? How does your ngAfterViewInit() look like now?